# Search mpeg / avi frames in linux

Tags: video, post-production, filter

I might have an unusual problem for this site; among other duties, I manage the wireless network for a large corporate campus.  As part of an upgrade to our wireless access-points, I used a metal bracket to mount an AP on a rail about 10 feet off the ground.  When it was mounted, the bottom part of the access-point was parallel with the floor.

A week later, our cabling technicians noticed that someone had bent the AP about 70 degrees upward; given the strength of the bracket, it took a lot of force to do this.  We have a security camera about 90 feet away from this AP, but the relevant area I care about is about 3% of the camera's image area.

Due to the fuzziness and small area in the video, our security team said it would take about 30 man-hours to search the video (one person watching it for 3.5 days... given restrictions in playback, they can't zoom in during fast forward); as such, they weren't interested in going farther.

*QUESTION*:

It seems like there might be some way to build a list of candidate time slots in the video, where this 3% area drastically changed from normal for a given time-frame... let's say at least 20-seconds.

TBH, the bracket is only $30; however, since our old-crusty security guy swore it couldn't be automated, I took it as a point of curiosity to see whether that's true.  Obviously there are commercial solutions... I'm looking for "free" in linux.

The file would be about 6GB.  Is there a linux CLI solution to this problem?  I just need to reduce the times we look at to something manageable.  Even if I had to use a python image analytics library like [OpenCV-python](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_table_of_contents_video/py_table_of_contents_video.html), that's a possibility but I'm hoping to (ab)use something like [`ffmpeg`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) for this purpose.  If there isn't such a tool, which [Open-CV](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/video/doc/video.html) function would be best for this job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FFMPEG doesn't really have the tools to do motion detection out of the box. You can certainly do the cropping using the [crop filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop): `-vf crop=w:h:x:y` where `w:h` is the size of your cropped area and `x:y` its coordinates in the original image. So your ffmpeg script might look like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -vf crop=123:45:67:89 output.mp4
```

Then you could find a frame of the output that contains no movement, export it to a still image, invert it and add it back to the video using [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) so that only parts of frames that are different would show up. Then use the [blackdetect](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blackdetect) filter to find frames that are black. Then you could use some shell-fu to delete those parts of the video and finally concatenate the remainder into one clip. Whew.

…or you could use openCV. Here's a ready-rolled script that does motion detection: https://github.com/RobinDavid/Motion-detection-OpenCV

Comment: when you say `-vf crop=w:h:x:y`, you're talking about [`ffmpeg` cropping](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/4563/4601), right?  When you say an "empty frame", I'm not sure how I would find that in a video file... I'm thinking the github project you mentioned might be the way to go

Comment: "empty frame" meaning a frame where nothing is happening. Yeah, use the script, unless you really want a learning excercise.